# google auth1 to oauth2 migration: Invalid authorization header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, google-oauth

I've a script to migrate from google oauth1 to oauth2 using oauth gem

everything seems right and i can't detect any problem with the headers but it still responding with: `Invalid authorization header.`

Here're the headers:

> opening connection to accounts.google.com:443...
>   opened
>   starting SSL for accounts.google.com:443...
>   SSL established
>   <- "POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: OAuth gem v0.4.7\r\nContent-Length: 193\r\nAuthorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"mykey.com\", oauth_nonce=\"LdBeaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxIxgd03U1DHYbs\", oauth_signature=\"wXIuxxxxxxxyxxxxj0%3D\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"1416497830\", oauth_token=\"1%2F9G2sKmQxxxxxxxxxxmDXbqqifoRBGUAii-D5sw2o\", oauth_version=\"1.0\"\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: accounts.google.com\r\n\r\n"
>
> <- "client_id=the_id&client_secret=C-7xxxxxxxxxboMcinh3ofV&grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Amigration%3Aoauth1"> "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n"
>
> -> "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
>
> -> "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate\r\n"
>
> -> "Pragma: no-cache\r\n"
>
> -> "Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT\r\n"
>
> -> "Date: Thu, 20 Nov 2014 12:37:03 GMT\r\n"
>
> -> "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff\r\n"
>
> -> "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN\r\n"
>
> -> "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block\r\n"
>
> -> "Server: GSE\r\n"
>
> -> "Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0.01\r\n"
>
> -> "Connection: close\r\n"
>
> -> "\r\n"
>
> reading all...
>
> -> "{\n  \"error\" : \"invalid_request\",\n  \"error_description\" : \"Invalid authorization 
>   header.\"\n}"
>
> read 90 bytes
>   Conn close

and here's the code:

```
oauth1_consumer_key    = "mykey"
oauth1_consumer_secret = "Gxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxqb8"

# OAuth 1 - User Token / Secret.
oauth1_token           = '1/9G2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxsw2o'
oauth1_secret          = 'a-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxmqG'

# OAuth 2 - Application ID / Secret
oauth2_client_id       = "the_id"
oauth2_client_secret   = "C-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxV"

# Migration Parameters.
params = {
  "grant_type"             => "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:migration:oauth1",
  "client_id"              => oauth2_client_id,
  "client_secret"          => oauth2_client_secret,
  # "oauth_signature_method" => "HMAC-SHA1"
}

# Create the consumer object.
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(
  oauth1_consumer_key,
  oauth1_consumer_secret,
  :site   => 'https://accounts.google.com',
  :scheme => :header
)


# Create the access token object.
access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.new(consumer, oauth1_token, oauth1_secret)

resp = access_token.post(
  "/o/oauth2/token",
  params,
  { 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' })

if resp.code.to_s != "200"
  # Raise an error.
  raise "#{resp.code} - #{resp.body}"
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: hi, i'ver verified your code. it works. not sure if you have the problem still

Comment: just one difference, my post url is __https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token__

Comment: yes it's working now! very weird. thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating the oauth gem, I tried it again and it worked.